# Is milliseconds a feature of the arrow time library in python

Tags: python, time

using this method

```
arrow.utcnow().format('YYYY_MM_DD_HH_mm_ss')
```

or something similar in arrow is it possible to get milliseconds added to the time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `S`,  `SS` or `SSS` in your format string to get milliseconds. So: `arrow.utcnow().format('YYYY_MM_DD_HH_mm_ss_SSS')`

Answer (score 5):

In fact you can use up to 6 digits for representing fractions of a second:

```
>>> now = arrow.utcnow()
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.0'
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.07'
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.073'
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSS')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.0735'
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSS')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.07359'
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.073591'
```

Starting from the 7th digit, the number start repeating (`073591` in my case):

```
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.073591'
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSSSS')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.073591073591'
>>> now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS')
u'2016-02-19 17:05:17.073591073591073591'
```