# Python Arrow milliseconds

Tags: python, python-arrow

I am trying to figure out one simple thing - how to convert `arrow.Arrow` object into milliseconds. I was reading following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510550/is-milliseconds-a-feature-of-the-arrow-time-library-in-python) but it still not clear to me how to get a long number in milliseconds.

I want something like:

```
def get_millis(time: arrow.Arrow):
     ... some magic goes here ...


print(get_millis(time))     
OUTPUT: 
1518129553227
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an inelegant answer: from your linked question, you can get the milliseconds as a string and then add them to the timestamp:

```
import arrow
now = arrow.utcnow()
s = now.timestamp
ms = int(now.format("SSS"))
print(s * 1000 + ms)
```

Which prints:

```
1518131043594
```

Answer (score 6):

Essentially the property you're looking for is

```
float_timestamp
```

E.g.

```
now_millisecs = round(arrow.utcnow().float_timestamp, 3)
now_microsecs = round(arrow.utcnow().float_timestamp, 6)
```

if you don't like the floating point, you can take it from here with:

```
str(now_millisecs).replace('.', '')
```

I personally leave the floating point representation for both visual convenience and ease of calculations (comparisons etc.).

Comment: If you want an integer number of milliseconds, rather than rounding, converting to a string, removing the decimal point, and converting back to an integer, you can just multiply by 1,000 and then round:  `round(arrow.utcnow().float_timestamp * 1000)`.  It's simpler, clearer, and slightly faster.

Comment: That said, your answer is absolutely the best one here.

Answer (score 3):

```
import arrow


def get_millis(time):
    return time.timestamp * 1000 + time.microsecond / 1000


print(get_millis(arrow.now()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also format to ms [official docs](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#supported-tokens) and then parse to int and cut it to the length than you needed.

```
int(arrow.utcnow().format("x")[:13])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a readable way:

```
import arrow

def get_millis():
    return int(arrow.utcnow().timestamp() * 1000)
```